# go multiple http clients with different tls configs

Tags: go, ssl

Trying to implement multiple http clients for calling multiple services, each with their own tls configurations (some need mTLS while some do not). However, I am seeing that the each new request is using the tls config from prior request, and not its own tls config? For example, I have 2 clients as below. When client-1 makes the first request, it verifies the server cert as expected. But when client-2 makes the next request, it is still trying to verify the server cert even though `InsecureSkipVerify: true` is configured for it.

client-1 has config:

```
tr := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport)
tr.TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{RootCAs: certPool, InsecureSkipVerify: false}
client1 := http.Client{Transport: tr, Timeout: timeout}
```

client-2 has config:

```
tr := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport)
tr.TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{RootCAs: certPool, InsecureSkipVerify: true}
client2 := http.Client{Transport: tr, Timeout: timeout}
```

response for the client2 request is **x509: certificate signed by unknown authority**. This shouldn't ideally happen because `InsecureSkipVerify: true` means the server certs are not verified.

Comment: You have 2 clients with the same config, you overwrote one with the other.

Comment: can you please elaborate? `InsecureSkipVerify` is different on both clients? these are also 2 separate files

Comment: You are assigning the same transport to each client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http.DefaultTransport` is a variable defined in the `http` package ([here](https://go.dev/src/net/http/transport.go#L43)) as:

```
var DefaultTransport RoundTripper = &Transport{
    Proxy: ProxyFromEnvironment,
    DialContext: defaultTransportDialContext(&net.Dialer{
        Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
        KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
    }),
    ForceAttemptHTTP2:     true,
    MaxIdleConns:          100,
    IdleConnTimeout:       90 * time.Second,
    TLSHandshakeTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
    ExpectContinueTimeout: 1 * time.Second,
}
```

You can use `DefaultTransport` to create multiple instances of `http.Client` but need to remember that they will all be using the same `Transport` (`DefaultTransport`). Changes to `DefaultTransport` will have an impact on all instances of `http.Client` that use `DefaultTransport`.

To resolve this either define your own `Transport` (perhaps by copying the above, this is covered in [the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#pkg-overview)) or make a copy (`tr := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).Clone()`) of the default transport before changing `TLSClientConfig`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation this makes sense. does this mean the last initialized client will overwrite all previously initialized clients with the default transport as JimB pointed out above?

Comment: Pretty much - it's complicated a little by [`onceSetNextProtoDefaults`](https://go.dev/src/net/http/transport.go#L359) which gets called the first time the `Transport` is used (e.g. [here](https://go.dev/src/net/http/transport.go#L505)). Note that it doesn't really "overwrite" the previously initialised clients - the clients hold a reference (interface/pointer) to the single variable and you are changing that variable.